# Where can I find good documentation on AWS API for Swift? (most of what I find is for Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My friends and I are developing on Swift using AWS for the first time.
We are having a hard time with AWS API for Swift because most of the docs are for objective-C.
Where can I find good docs on Swift?

Comment: have a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html#getting-started-with-swift)

Comment: thanks, but I guess this is what I already looked at.

Comment: The AWS Swift documentation is poor. The main page shows you how to configure it and perform a query to list all available tables but not how to query further with expressions, handle the return of the data, delete data, edit data etc.

Answer (score 0):

[aws/aws-sdk-ios](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios) go to this link and scroll down a bit, you will find the headline [Getting Started with Swift](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios#getting-started-with-swift).
I have followed the same to implement on my side. I hope it will be helpful for you too.